# I can not pass the certain test in js case on codesignal.com? am I wrong or something wrong with this website?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, filtering

So I am doing some exercises with JavaScript in codesignal.com.
This is my Code.

This is a Task:

> The next step is to support the operation for finding the nearest integer in the container greater than the provided one:
>
> GET_NEXT  should return the minimal integer in the container that is strictly greater than the provided value. In case there is no such integer in the container, return empty string.

All test cases are passed except the last one

**TEST CASE:**

```
`> Input:
queries:
[["ADD","0"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["ADD","11"], 
 ["ADD","22"], 
 ["ADD","3"], 
 ["ADD","5"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","0"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","1"], 
 ["REMOVE","1"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","1"], 
 ["ADD","0"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["ADD","2"], 
 ["ADD","1"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","1"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","2"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","3"], 
 ["GET_NEXT","5"]]
Output:
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "3", "true", "3", "", "", "", "", "2", "3", "5", ""]
Expected Output:
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "3", "true", "3", "", "", "", "", "2", "3", "5", "11"]`
```

**Here Is My Code**

```
function solution(queries) {
const values = [];
const results = [];

queries.map(query =>{
    const [operation, value] = query;
    
    if(operation === "ADD"){
        values.push(value);
        results.push("")
    }
    
    if(operation === "EXISTS"){
        const exists = values.includes(value);
        results.push(exists.toString())
    }
   if(operation === "REMOVE"){
        const indexOfValue = values.indexOf(value);
        const exists = values.includes(value);
        
        if(exists){
        values.splice(indexOfValue, 1);
        }
        
        results.push(exists.toString())
    }
  if(operation === "GET_NEXT"){
    const filteredValues = values.filter(val => val > value);
    filteredValues.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const nextValue = filteredValues[0] || "";
    results.push(nextValue);
    }
});

return results;
}
```

what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
const [operation, value] = query;
…
const filteredValues = values.filter(val => val > value);
```

Query is something like `["ADD","11"]` or `["GET_NEXT", "5"]`, so an array of two character strings. But when you compare character strings, they're compared lexicographically, like in a phone book:

```
>>> "5" > "11"
true
```

But you want to interpret the input character strings as Numbers. So convert the second argument of `query` to a Number:

```
const [operation, stringValue] = query;
const value = Number(stringValue);
```

Do numeric work on Numbers, and then convert back to a string if necessary.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a lot. That was very stupid by my side. Have a good day